# Using an inequality to select elements from a list and then plotting the results

Tags: plotting, curated-data, probability-or-statistics

Okay, here is the information that I have.

```
closingValues = 
  FinancialData["^GSPC", "Close", {"Jan 1., 2000", "Jan 1., 2012"}, 
   "Value"];
logr = Differences[Log[closingValues]];

x = Tally[Sort[Round[logr, .001]]];
```

What I want to do is this:

(logr >= x) / Length[logr]

I want to count all the values in logr that are greater than or equal to x (there are about 110 or so values in x).

I also need help on plotting a graph where x is on the x-axis, and the resulting number above is on the y-axis.

Any help or advice, or leading me to any direction of solving my problem is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What elements of "logr" and "x" are you trying to compare? The list x already consists of elements in logr, just rounded to the nearest 0.001. Are you trying to do an element by element compare?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is find typical values of logr, which i denoted x. And then count which values of logr are greater than x. I didn't know how to find "typical values" so I tallied all of the rounded values and am going to use those.

Comment: If you are looking for values in logr that are greater than the max element in x (hence all elements in x), all you will find are the ones that were rounded down to the max value in x. Am I right?

Comment: Right. So let's say the max value was .05, then I want to find count all values in logr that are greater than .05, and then divide how ever many numbers I found that were greater than .05 by Length[logr]. But instead of using just the max value, I want to do it for all listed values in x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps use `UnitStep` and `Mean`.  This should be pretty fast.

```
f[logr_, x_] := Mean[UnitStep[logr - x]]

f[logr, 0]

(*1597/3018*)
```

Now to plot it.

```
Plot[f[logr, t], {t, -.1, .1}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Andy, I don't think this is what I'm trying to do, but I greatly appreciate you trying to help.
What I wanted to do is find all values in logr that is greater than the first value in x (so I essentially count however many values are larger than x), and then divide by the length of logr (like a probability). And then repeat with the next value in x.

Comment: This counts all values in `logr` that are greater than a given `x` value and divides by the number of elements in `logr`.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Actually, this does what you want, much more easily than what I was doing. Hats off!

Comment: Ooh, my confusion lies in the := Mean[UnitStep[logr - x]] part. Could you explain what it is doing for me?

Comment: `UnitStep` is listable and logr-x gives a list of numbers. If they are negative `UnitStep` gives 0 otherwise it gives 1. Mean of a list of zero's and 1's is the same as counting the non-negative values and dividing by the number of elements.

Comment: Andy or anyone, What if I wanted to take the log of the resulting values and plot it with the log of the x values? How would I do that?
Thank you guys so much for helping me!

Comment: Well, you have negative `x` values in that list, so that might be a problem.

Comment: Oh, right. So let's say we remove those negative x values, then how would I continue from there?

Comment: You could use `LogLogPlot` instead of `Plot`.

Comment: Okay, this is what I did:
I took the absolute value of x to rid of the negative values.
I tried doing LogLogPlot and I received an error. So this is what I did

    LogPlot[f[Abs[logr], t], {t, 0, Max[logr]}]
Is this correct, or did I do this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

(Cannot connect to `FinancialData`, so I used `fakeReturns` instead of `logr`.)

```
 fakeReturns = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 600];

 Plot[SurvivalFunction[HistogramDistribution[fakeReturns], x], {x, -3, 3},
   Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Or, `Histogram` with  `Round[logr,.001]` ("typical values") as bin delimiters and `"SF"` (i.e., `SurvivalFunction`) as the height function gives:

```
Histogram[fakeReturns, {Union@Round[fakeReturns, 0.1]}, "SF", PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

or, with a different specification of "typical" values:

```
 Histogram[fakeReturns, {Union@Round[fakeReturns, 0.01]}, "SF", PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: OOH! That seems simple also!
Now what if I wanted to take the log of the resulting values and plot it with the log of the x values? How would I do that?

Comment: @user4341, `fakeReturns` data has negative values as it is intended to represent your `logr` (`Differences[Log[closingPrices]]`, that is, daily returns). With positive-valued data, you can use `Histogram` option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}` get both axes in log scale.